# Pixel offset when there is multiple children

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

Found a strange behaviour that when I keep adding or toggle display sprite object. That makes my game screen shakes when toggle some of optional UIs .

Tried to reproduce this issue with simplified codes. Here is the experiment.
The red line shows the original position of first square.png

[image: normal state]

When I keep adding sprites on the same position, appears that pixels moved, the square not stack up in different positions

[image: added many children]

When hiding sprite except the first square, seems it back to correct position

[image: hide children]

```
var MyScene = cc.Scene.extend({

   onEnterTransitionDidFinish: function(){

       this._super();

       this.initComponents();


   },

    initComponents: function () {

       //create additional square container
        var node = new cc.Node();
        this.node = node;
        node.setPosition(90, 90);
        this.attach(node);
        this.addChild(node);

        //draw first square
        var sprite = new cc.Sprite("square.png");
        sprite.setPosition(50,50);
        this.addChild(sprite);


        //listen to keyboard, add square / toggle
        if ('keyboard' in cc.sys.capabilities) {
            cc.eventManager.addListener({
                event: cc.EventListener.KEYBOARD,
                onKeyPressed: function (keyCode, event) {
                    switch (keyCode) {
                        //toggle additional squares
                        case cc.KEY.q:
                            this.node.setVisible(!this.node.isVisible());
                            break;
                        //attach more squares
                        case cc.KEY.w:
                            this.attach(node);
                            break;
                    }
                }.bind(this)
            }, this);
        }

        //draw measure line
        var line = new cc.DrawNode();
        line.drawRect(cc.p(130,0), cc.p(132,150),cc.color(255,0,0,255),0);
        this.addChild(line);

    },
    /**
     * Attach more squares
     * @param node
     */
    attach: function (node) {
        var xp = 0;
        var yp = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var sp = new cc.Sprite("square.png");
            node.addChild(sp);
            sp.setPosition(xp * 180, yp * 180);

            xp++;
            if (xp > 15) {
                xp = 0;
                yp++;
            }
        }
    }

});
```

[image: square.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the issue can be improved / resolve by assign everything into negative z order

```
var children = this.getChildren();
        var avicinarAka = -99999;
        for (var k in children) {
            if (children[k]) {
                children[k].setLocalZOrder(avicinarAka++);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer you without the context, what API do you use ? What is cc ?
Anyway, by comparing the screenshots you provided it seems that your squares effectively moved away. The strange corners appears because you don't clear the screen between each frame.
This produce a trail, it's not the pixels that moved, but the squares themselves.

Try those steps :

- print their positions each time you add a new sprite
- fix the length of view
- try to print a square instead of using an image

Edit your question if you have more information, and then I will edit this answer according to your additional information.

Comment: its cocos2d-js. 
all the new sprites are in same position
seems the problem is only on bitmap, live draw graphics wont have the issue